# Struts 1.x and AJAX: Action-Class doesn't get request

Tags: java, ajax, struts, struts-1, no-response

I try to develope a simple communication between Struts 1.x and Ajax.
I have a jsp with ajax-code, which should send a "username" and "password" to an Action-Class.

The AJAX-Code is fine, but the Action-Class doesn't get the response of AJAX.

Q: How do you know that the Action-Class doesn't get the request?

A: Because i wrote into the Action-Class a System.out.println("..."), which is never used while testing the application.

I tried this also without AJAX, just a normal "form" into the jsp which sends the data to the Action-Class. There it is, it works without problems. It get's the data and prints the message of println("...").

My Question is, why the Action-Class doesn't get the request of AJAX?

Here is some Code-Snippet:

///JSP - Ajax-script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var resultMsg = "";
        var xmlHttp;

        function doAjaxPost() {

            resultMsg = "";
            var name = document.getElementById("username").value;               
            var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
            //alert(resultMsg);
            var url = "/Index.do?username=" + name + "&password=" + pw;
            document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML ="";
            document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>start doAjaxPost()...\n";
            //alert(resultMsg);
            if (url != "") {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers
                    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>implement new XMLHttpRequest...\n";
                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>implement new ActiveXObject(' Microsoft.XMLHTTP')...\n";
                }
                try {
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>check state...\n";
                    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = processMessage;
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>open connection...\n";
                    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>send data...\n";
                    xmlHttp.send(null);
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>...finished";
                } catch (e) {
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>\n/////////" + e + "/////////\n\n";
                    alert(resultMsg);
                }
            }

        }

        function processMessage() {
            document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>\tpm: check state...\n";
            document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>\tpm: state:\t" + xmlHttp.readyState + "\n";
            //alert(resultMsg);
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { // Complete
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) { // OK response
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>\tpm: set textfield ...\n";
                    document.getElementById("username").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>\tpm: set <p>-tag ...\n";
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>No response: "+xmlHttp.status;
                }
            }else{
                document.getElementById("responseMessage").innerHTML += "<br>State not ready: "+xmlHttp.readyState;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

///struts-config.xml

```
<!-- Form mapping -->   
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="indexForm" type="com.name.forms.IndexForm"/>
</form-beans>

<!-- Action mapping -->
<action-mappings>
    <action name="indexForm" path="/Index" type="com.name.actions.IndexAction"
        scope="request" parameter="/index.jsp" />
```

///IndexAction.java Class

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    IndexForm ajaxForm = (IndexForm) form;
    System.out.println("Start IndexAction...");
    // response.setContentType("text/text;charset=utf-8");
    // response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // String content = (String) request.getParameter("name");
    out.println("Hello " + ajaxForm.getUsername()+"<br>Ur PW:"+ajaxForm.getPassword());
    out.flush();
    return null;
}
```

///Generated Message from the JSP (while tested in firefox)

**start doAjaxPost()...

implement httpReq...

check state...

open connection...

pm: check state...   ///pm stands for the function processMessage() in the jsp

pm: state: 1

State not ready: 1

send data...

...finished

pm: check state...

pm: state: 2

State not ready: 2

pm: check state...

pm: state: 3

State not ready: 3

pm: check state...

pm: state: 4

No response: 404**

And as i sayed before, the Eclipse-Console didn't printed the message from the Action-Class which leads me to the thought that the Action-Class doesn't get the request of AJAX.

It's mysteriouse because it works without ajax and i cant's see the problem...
I hope someone can help me.
And sorry for my bad English :S

Comment: You need to check the wire, check any filters or custom request processing in your app, etc. There's no reason Ajax won't work with S1, it's done all the time.

Comment: There aren't any filters or custom-requests implemented yet.
i don't even know where to set the configurations for them :S

the project is very simple. just one Action- and one Form-Classe and a JSP (and the web- and struts-config.xml).

Comment: Then check what you're actually sending, the actual URL, the headers, everything.

Comment: okay i got it!
the problem was the URL, i added this to the url in the jsp "http://localhost:8080/Application/Index.do..."

just because the port wasn't given, ajax sended the information to localhost without port where the application isn't reachable!

thanks alot, your hint lead us to the way